# GROUP by Largest String for all the substrings

Tags: sql, postgresql, group-by, substring

I have a table like this where some rows have the same grp but different names. I want to group them by name such that all the substrings after removing nonalphanumeric characters are aggregated together and grouped by the largest string. The null value is considered the substring of all the strings.

| grp | name | value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | ab&c | 10 |
| 1 | abc d e | 56 |
| 1 | ab | 21 |
| 1 | a | 23 |
| 1 | xy | 34 |
| 1 | [null] | 1 |
| 2 | fgh | 87 |

Desired result

| grp | name | value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | abcde | 111 |
| 1 | xy | 34 |
| 2 | fgh | 87 |

My query-

```
Select grp, 
regexp_replace(name,'[^a-zA-Z0-9]+', '', 'g') name, sum(value) value
from table
group by grp,
regexp_replace(name,'[^a-zA-Z0-9]+', '', 'g');
```

Result

| grp | name | value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | abc | 10 |
| 1 | abcde | 56 |
| 1 | ab | 21 |
| 1 | a | 23 |
| 1 | xy | 34 |
| 1 | [null] | 1 |
| 2 | fgh | 87 |

What changes should I make in my query?

Comment: how would you group `abcd` and `abce` ?

Comment: Is `[null]` a `NULL` value or is it a string with brackets and the word "*null*" in it? If your case is the latter one, consider avoiding null values represented as strings as it adds up unnecessary complexity.

Comment: Why is the 1 for the `NULL` included in with the `grp` = 1, `abcde` grouping value total and not the `grp` = 1, `xy` grouping value total? What **determines** this?

Comment: Take a look [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=de0bbb34365f698162819e9db151ced5) to see the problem with `NULL`s.

Comment: NULL is considered a substring of both abcde and xy. But it will be grouped with the abcde, since length (abcde) > length(xy). Basically NULL will be a substring of every string but it will be grouped with the longest string of the same grp.

Comment: What would you do if you had another row `fgh`?

Comment: @Charlieface - see the new answer I posted - with `CROSS JOIN LATERAL` and now a community wiki answer.

Answer (score 1):

To solve this problem, I did the following (all of the code below is available on the fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=b02107991d1824e50c48bbba770ee332)).

```
CREATE TABLE test 
(
  grp  SMALLINT NOT NULL,
  name TEXT         NULL,
  value SMALLINT NOT NULL
);
```

and populate it using your data + extra for testing:

```
INSERT INTO test VALUES
(1, 'ab&c',     10),
(1, 'abc d e',  56),
(1, 'ab',   21),
(1, 'a',        23),

(1, NULL, 1000000),

(1, 'r*&%$s',  100),  -- added for testing.
(1, 'rs__t',   101),
(1, 'rs__tu', 101),

(1, 'xy',    1111),

(1, NULL, 1000000),

(2, 'fgh',     87),

(2, 'fgh',     13),  -- For Charlieface

(2, NULL, 1000000),

(2, 'x',       50),
(2, 'x',      150),
(2, 'x----y',  100);
```

Then, you can use this query:

```
WITH t1 AS
(
  SELECT 
    grp, n_str,
    LAG(n_str) OVER (PARTITION BY grp ORDER BY grp, n_str),
    CASE
      WHEN 
        LAG(n_str) OVER (PARTITION BY grp ORDER BY grp, n_str) IS NULL
      OR
        POSITION
        (
          LAG(n_str) OVER (PARTITION BY grp ORDER BY grp, n_str)
          IN
          n_str
        ) = 0
      THEN 1
      ELSE 0
    END AS change,
    value
  FROM
    test t1
  CROSS JOIN LATERAL 
  (
    VALUES
    (
      REGEXP_REPLACE(name,'[^a-zA-Z0-9]+', '', 'g')
    ) 
  ) AS v(n_str)
  WHERE n_str IS NOT NULL
), t2 AS
(
  SELECT 
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY grp, s_change ORDER BY grp, n_str DESC) AS rn,
    grp, n_str, 
    SUM(value) OVER (PARTITION BY grp, s_change) AS s_val,
    MAX(LENGTH(n_str)) OVER (PARTITION BY grp) AS max_nom
  FROM
  (
    SELECT 
      grp, n_str, change,
      SUM(change) OVER (ORDER BY grp, n_str) AS s_change,
      value
    FROM 
      t1 
    ORDER BY grp, n_str DESC
  ) AS sub1
), t3 AS
(
  SELECT
    grp, SUM(value) AS null_sum
  FROM
    test
  WHERE name IS NULL
  GROUP BY grp
)
SELECT x.grp, x.n_str, x.s_val + y.null_sum
FROM t2 x
JOIN t3 y
  ON x.max_nom = LENGTH(x.n_str) AND x.grp = y.grp
UNION 
SELECT grp, n_str, s_val
FROM 
  t2 WHERE max_nom != LENGTH(n_str) AND rn = 1
ORDER BY grp, n_str;
```

Result:

```
grp  n_str  ?column?
  1  abcde   2000110
  1   rstu       302
  1     xy      1111
  2    fgh   1000100
  2     xy       300
```

A  few points to note:

- Please **always** provide a fiddle when you ask questions such as this one with tables and data - it provides a single source of truth for the question and eliminates duplication of effort on the part of those trying to help you!
- You haven't been very clear about what, exactly, should happen with `NULL`s - do the `values` count towards the `SUM()`? You can vary the `CASE` statement as required.
- What happens when there's a tie in the number of characters in the string? I've included an example in the fiddle, where you get the draws - but you may wish to sort alphabetically (or some other method)?
- There appears to be an error in your provided sums for the values (even taking account of counting or not values for `NULL` for the `name` field).
- Finally, you **don't** want to `GROUP BY` the largest string - you want to `GROUP BY` the `grp` fields + the `SUM()` of the values in the the given `grp` records and **then** pick out the longest alphanumeric string in that grouping. It would be interesting to know **why** you want to do this?

Comment: •The null values should count towards the sum if they belong to the same grp
•I haven't come across such a case where the names are in the same grp and have same length but different characters.
•Yes, the sum value was incorrect. Thanks for pointing it out. I have corrected it now.
•Basically, the data is not clean, so we have name entered incorrectly. I want to group by a grp and name and calculate the sum for that grp and name.1 'abc' & 1 'ab', these two belong to the same grp but their name is entered incorrectly. So they should be grouped together with the final name as 'abc'.

Comment: So, is my answer correct or not? Or even helpful? I see what you mean about unclean data - I think everybody comes across that! I think that you should, to the greatest extent possible, have data entry controls in your app obviously, but also in the PostgreSQL server itself! Not allowing strings with non-alphanumerics for example? Also, what about hyphens and (to a lesser extent) underscores?

Comment: Yes, your answer is correct and helpful. Thank you so much. 

Hyphens and underscores are also removed while comparing the strings. 

Thank you for the suggestions.

Comment: A follow-up question, 
For a record like 1 'xy' 34, I want to group it separately as the name 'xy' is not a substring of 'abcde'. 
How would I do it?